# 4 threads as services in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to implement 4 threads as services in  android. How di i do that. Can anyone suggest a good example for the same.?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "threads as services"?

Comment: Why do you want four threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are not threads - Services can create additional Threads.

So the first question you need to ask yourself: Do you really need 4 Services with one Thread or or is one Service with 4 Threads enough.

Then you create one or more Services and in the onCreate you create threads as you do normally do on Java.

Comment: On 2nd thought you might want to use  onStartCommand instead of on onCreate. And important: you must stop/join your threads in onDestroy.